# Sort by score & an int field value

Tags: solr

I need to sort documents returned in order of (descending) score & (descending) value of an int field within the document. How do I ensure proper sort order as well as good performance ?

I don't need the sort-order defined by `sort=score desc,intField desc`.
The sort order needs to be somewhat like what will be delivered using product function of `score`*`fieldVal` as effective score for sort order. But I don't need exact product for sorting. Approximations are ok, & this is just to roughly define the sort order I need.

I can see a few possible ways to accomplish this:

> **1. Use a customized function of score for `sort`**
>
> **2. Use query time boost to increase the score using the int field value for boost**

I'm new to Solr & don't understand the performance implications of each of above case. Also, don't know if there are other better ways to accomplish what I am trying to do. So how do I build **performance friendly query to achieve this sort order** ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solr Function Query : How to use "score" field for creating custom scoring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36838557/solr-function-query-how-to-use-score-field-for-creating-custom-scoring)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at solr function queries

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/function-queries.html#FunctionQueries-SortByFunction

Example:
&sort=product(score, fieldVal)